# big-theta() and big-O() notations

Tags: algorithm, big-o

what will be the big-theta() and big-O() notations. for this

> (2^n) - (n x 2^n)

or in another question is n2^n greater than 2^n in time complexity ?

Comment: Hello. Please take a minute to read the [help] section on asking homework questions.

Comment: thank you @OneCricketeer , but this question is not a homework question.

Comment: Is your question regarding whether O(n*2^n) is greater than O(2^n)?

Answer (score 2):

Your question does not make sense because your function is not positive for large n. If I get your notation you have (1-n)*(2^n) which is kind of O(-2^n).
But, as I said, that is not really correct because the O and Theta abstraction does not work for negative functions. Hence, a minus can only used if the RHS term is smaller for large numbers.